# Consuming webservice(wsdl) that require to pass array

Tags: c#

I need to create a client that is uploading orders to a third party provider for processing. Here is wsdl link: http://support.dqtech.com/DQIAuto_WS/service.asmx?WSDL

I'm having issue how to initialize array based on wsdl.
So far i ass web service to my project and can see all methods and properties from WSDl.

My idea was to use List and convert it to Array and pass it but I'm getting index exception error when i try to loop and assign values. 
DQ is my web service
Any help or different idea how to code this?
here is portion of my code:

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using OrderImport.DQ;



private void btnTransmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap");


        List<cOrder> cOrderl = new List<cOrder>();
        List<ArrayOfCOrderDetail> orderDetails = new List<ArrayOfCOrderDetail>();
        List<cOrderDetail> cOrderDetails = new List<cOrderDetail>();           

        for (i=0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {

            iOrd += 1;
            cOrderl[iOrd] = new DQ.cOrder
            {
                Company = "1",
                Location = "LOC1",
                OrderType = "O",
                OrderNumber = dtOrders.Rows[i]["OrderNumber"].ToString(),
                ShipmentNumber="",
                InvoiceNumber= dtOrders.Rows[i]["InvNumber"].ToString(),
                OrderDateTime= dtOrders.Rows[i]["OrderDate"].ToString(),
                ReqDate="",
                Changed="",
                ChangeDateTime="",
                PONumber= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShortPO"].ToString(),
                WrittenByName="",
                WrittenByCode= dtOrders.Rows[i]["WritenBy"].ToString(),
                SalesmanName="",
                SalesmanCode= dtOrders.Rows[i]["SalesRepId"].ToString(),
                Customer=new DQ.cCustomer
                {
                    CustomerNumber= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustomerId"].ToString(),
                    CustomerName= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustName"].ToString(),
                    Address=new DQ.cAddress
                    {
                        Address1= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustAddress1"].ToString(),
                        Address2= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustAddress2"].ToString(),
                        City= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustCity"].ToString(),
                        State= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustState"].ToString(),
                        Zip= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustZip"].ToString(),
                        Latitude=0,
                        Longitude=0
                    },
                    Contact=new DQ.cContact
                    {
                        Contact="",
                        Phone= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustPhone"].ToString(),
                        Fax=""
                    },
                    SalespersonCode=""
                },
                Job=new DQ.cJob
                {
                    Company="",
                    CustomerNumber= dtOrders.Rows[i]["CustomerId"].ToString(),
                    JobNumber= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToId"].ToString(),
                    JobName= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToName"].ToString(),
                    Address=new DQ.cAddress
                    {
                        Address1= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToAddress1"].ToString(),
                        Address2= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToAddress2"].ToString(),
                        City=dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToCity"].ToString(),
                        State= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToState"].ToString(),
                        Zip= dtOrders.Rows[i]["ShipToZip"].ToString(),
                        Latitude=0,
                        Longitude=0
                    },
                },
                TotalAmount="",
                TotalCost="",
                WeightTotal= dtOrders.Rows[i]["OrderWeight"].ToString(),
                VolumeTotal= dtOrders.Rows[i]["OrderCBF"].ToString(),
                ShipVia= dtOrders.Rows[i]["Route"].ToString(),
                MapZone= dtOrders.Rows[i]["Route"].ToString(),
                Rating="",
                Territory="",
                //OrderDetail=orderDetailArray[]
            };
        }




    }
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `iOrd` and why do you increment it at the beginning of the loop? `List<T>` has a zero-based index so you are automatically starting at the second item of `cOrderl`.

Comment: the initial value is -1, so the first index is 0, but im getting this error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'